# Error in the query

Tags: mysql

```
$sql="SELECT users.*,designation.designation FROM `users` LEFT JOIN designation ON users.desgid=designation.id WHERE deptid='$deptid'"
```

I get deptid is ambigous when i execute the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `deptid` is in both the `users` and `designation` table.  If so, you need to put

```
... WHERE users.deptid='$deptid'
```

or

```
... WHERE designation.deptid='$deptid'
```

as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There is a column named `deptid` in both your `users` table and your `designation` table.  Qualify the column name in your WHERE clause by saying "table_name.deptid"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are joining two tables with deptid, it is unknown which table it should come from.  You'll have to qualify like you do with designation in the SELECT.

```
WHERE designation.deptid='$deptid'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT users.*,designation.designation FROM `users` LEFT JOIN designation ON users.desgid=designation.id WHERE deptid=$deptid"
```